# Android upgrading SQLite - table not modified

Tags: android, sqlite, upgrade

I have a problem upgrading SQLite. I'm using SQLiteOpenHelper and I just added one column, changed database version, but the problem is, that the new column is not shown(is not made). As far as I can see, the OnCreate and OnUpgrade are called correctly, but I don't know why the new tables are not made. I only added in table "smeri" the last column "Online"

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 16;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "RasicaDB";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_NAME_mainpoints = "mainpoints";
private static final String TABLE_NAME_smeri = "smeri";
private static final String TABLE_NAME_povezave = "povezave";

// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY1_ID = "ID";
private static final String KEY1_X = "X";
private static final String KEY1_Y = "Y";

private static final String KEY2_ID = "ID";
private static final String KEY2_ime = "Ime";
private static final String KEY2_tezavnost = "Tezavnost";
private static final String KEY2_opis = "Opis";
private static final String KEY2_avtor = "Avtor";
private static final String KEY2_datum = "Datum";
private static final String KEY2_online = "Online";

private static final String KEY3_IDsmeri = "IDsmeri";
private static final String KEY3_IDtocke = "IDtocke";
private static final String KEY3_vrstaTocke = "vrstaTocke";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    Log.e("log_tag", "ON CREATE!!!!!!!!");

    String CREATE_mainpoints_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_mainpoints + "("
            + KEY1_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + KEY1_X + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY1_Y + " INTEGER" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_mainpoints_TABLE);


    String CREATE_smeri_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_smeri + "("
            + KEY2_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + KEY2_ime + " TEXT,"
            + KEY2_tezavnost + " TEXT,"
            + KEY2_opis + " TEXT,"
            + KEY2_avtor + " TEXT,"
            + KEY2_datum + " TEXT,"
            + KEY2_online + " INTEGER" + ")";
    Log.e("log_tag", ""+CREATE_smeri_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_smeri_TABLE);

    String CREATE_povezave_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_povezave + "("
            + KEY3_IDsmeri + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY3_IDtocke + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY3_vrstaTocke + " INTEGER " + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_povezave_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    Log.e("log_tag", "ON UPGRADE!!!!!!!!");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME_mainpoints);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME_smeri);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME_povezave);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
 public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 16;

        // Database Name
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "RasicaDB";

        // Contacts table name
        private static final String TABLE_NAME_mainpoints = "mainpoints";
        private static final String TABLE_NAME_smeri = "smeri";
        private static final String TABLE_NAME_povezave = "povezave";

        // Contacts Table Columns names
        private static final String KEY1_ID = "ID";
        private static final String KEY1_X = "X";
        private static final String KEY1_Y = "Y";

        private static final String KEY2_ID = "ID";
        private static final String KEY2_ime = "Ime";
        private static final String KEY2_tezavnost = "Tezavnost";
        private static final String KEY2_opis = "Opis";
        private static final String KEY2_avtor = "Avtor";
        private static final String KEY2_datum = "Datum";
        private static final String KEY2_online = "Online";

        private static final String KEY3_IDsmeri = "IDsmeri";
        private static final String KEY3_IDtocke = "IDtocke";
        private static final String KEY3_vrstaTocke = "vrstaTocke";

        public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "ON CREATE!!!!!!!!");

            String CREATE_mainpoints_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_mainpoints + "("
                    + KEY1_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                    + KEY1_X + " INTEGER,"
                    + KEY1_Y + " INTEGER" + ")";
            db.execSQL(CREATE_mainpoints_TABLE);


            String CREATE_smeri_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_smeri + "("
                    + KEY2_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                    + KEY2_ime + " TEXT,"
                    + KEY2_tezavnost + " TEXT,"
                    + KEY2_opis + " TEXT,"
                    + KEY2_avtor + " TEXT,"
                    + KEY2_datum + " TEXT,"
                    + KEY2_online + " INTEGER" + ")";
            Log.e("log_tag", ""+CREATE_smeri_TABLE);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_smeri_TABLE);

            String CREATE_povezave_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_povezave + "("
                    + KEY3_IDsmeri + " INTEGER,"
                    + KEY3_IDtocke + " INTEGER,"
                    + KEY3_vrstaTocke + " INTEGER " + ")";
            db.execSQL(CREATE_povezave_TABLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // Drop older table if existed
            try{
                if(oldVersion<16){
                    db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_smeri +" ADD column "+KEY2_online+ " INTEGER "); 
                }   
            }catch(SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to put table name in quotes

`db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '" + TABLE_NAME_mainpoints +"'");`

Comment: tried, not working :/ when the upgrade happens, all tables got deleted, but then they are created in the same way they were before, even if i comment whole creation process of one table, it still gets created :s

Comment: well, i thought that also :s cant find the problem

Comment: Are you sure you're modified code is actually being run? If the tables are deleted and then re-created but with the old schema then it sounds like you're just running the old version of the app. I'd suggest you modify your Log.e to include something new so that you definitely know your code is running. You can also add version numbering into your manifest xml which I use a lot to make sure I know which version is running.

Comment: i made that Log.e statement when my code was not working anymore, so yes, this code is running.

Answer (score 0):

you can try it to add column

```
db.execSQL("alter table smeri add column Online int");
```